# Simplest layout thing driving me crazy

Tags: android

I've a `TextView` inside a `CardView`. Now the problem is when I use setText method on the `TextView` it's giving me `nullPointerException`. According to my tests `textViewAuthor` in the below code is `null` even after initializing it. Weird part is `textViewName` which is initialized the same way is not null. Why is it staying null even after assigning a view?

```
public class EBooksRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EBooksRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private String[] ebookName, ebookAuthor;
    private OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public EBooksRecyclerViewAdapter(String[] ebookName, String[] ebookAuthor) {
        this.ebookName = ebookName;
        this.ebookAuthor = ebookAuthor;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textViewName, textViewAuthor;
        private CardView cardView;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            textViewName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);     //not null
            textViewAuthor = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textViewAuthor); //NULL !!
            if(textViewName == null)
                Log.e("textViewAuthor","null");
            if(textViewAuthor == null)
                Log.e("textViewAuthor","null");

            cardView = (CardView)v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mItemClickListener.onItemClick(textViewName.getText().toString());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener){
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(String eventName);
    }

    @Override
    public EBooksRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(
            ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.event_card_view, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.e("NAME", ebookName[position]);     //not null
        Log.e("AUTHOR", ebookAuthor[position]); //not null

        holder.textViewName.setText(ebookName[position]);
        holder.textViewAuthor.setText(ebookAuthor[position]); //nullPointerException
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ebookName.length;
    }
}
```

Here's my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.25">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_margin="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewAuthor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_margin="2dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your initialising textViewAuthor, but you're using holder.textViewAuthor, which is not the same. You're not showing how you're initialising holder. I know you have some debug logging in there, but I still wonder.

Comment: Have u tried to rebuild your project?

Comment: @ci_ There's no problem with holder as `textViewName` works good.

Comment: @Laurenswuyts Yes I tried to rebuild the project but in vain.

Comment: @Ryan please provide more code, i.e. for inflation part, creating view holder.

Comment: Clean your project and see if regenerated R.java.class fixes the issue.

Comment: @IgorFilippov It's a `RecyclerView`. I've added the whole class.

Comment: @Dusan That's not working.

Comment: Also, try to hard-code the id of an element to see if the problem is caused by messed up R class.

Comment: @Dusan "hard-code the id" how to do that?

Comment: Try `android:id="12345"` and `textViewAuthor = (TextView)v.findViewById(12345);`

Comment: While ago when I was using Eclipse there were a strange bug which cause NullPointer on views which actually exists in my layouts. So i suggests a few steps. Uninstall your application from device and install it again with clean build. Restart Android Studio or clear it's cache and try again.

Comment: @Dusan I'm using AndroidStudio and that doesn't seem to work here. It gives error "cannot resolve symbol Test".

Comment: @Android-Developer I tried all of that but nothing is working.

Comment: @Ryan, forget about hard-coding seems that is not possible...

Comment: Right now they aren't quite the same.  Try making them copy-and-paste twins of each other, differing only in the android:id, and while you are at it make some other change, such as setting initial text values, which will prove that what you are testing is built from your latest changes.

Comment: Same problem if you use `android:id="@id/textViewAuthor"` instead of `android:id="@+id/textViewAuthor"` (removed +)?

Comment: Problem solved. I was inflating a wrong `CardView` in `onCreateViewHolder`. The `event_card_view` does not have `textViewAuthor`. But then it shouldn't even allow me to compile as the current inflated view don't have `textViewAuthor`.